TPH using two properties
I am working on a project where I have a Reminders API.
My entities are made of two important properties : Frequency and Type.
Here is the base classes :
public abstract class ReminderDao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public abstract ReminderFrequency Frequency { get; }
    public abstract ReminderType Type { get; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OneTimeReminderDao : ReminderDao
{
    public override ReminderFrequency Frequency => ReminderFrequency.OneTime;

    // OneTime
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RecurringReminderDao : ReminderDao
{
    public override ReminderFrequency Frequency => ReminderFrequency.Recurring;

    // Recurring
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
}

Here is the implementations:
public sealed class AppointmentOneTimeReminderDao : OneTimeReminderDao
{
    public override ReminderType Type => ReminderType.Appointment;
}

public sealed class AppointmentRecurringReminderDao : RecurringReminderDao
{
    public override ReminderType Type => ReminderType.Appointment;
}

I am stuck because I don't know how to make a good TPH inheritance in order to get in a same table Reminders the one time and the recurring reminders with typed reminders.
I am taking any advice ! Thanks a lot !

How is this related to the SQL language? Perhaps you should have used the  tag instead?

Frequency is more of a behaviour of a reminder than a discriminator so I would recommend just using a discriminator on Type where the frequency is just a property. Overall inheritance should be avoided unless it provides very clear benefit to a design. If there are clear use cases for different types of reminders where code paths are distinct  for different types then it can make sense to inherit. For instance it makes sense to inherit a Car vs. Bus from a base Vehicle, but overkill to have a RedCar or FourDoorCar etc. (or totally overboard FourDoorRedCar :)
